# Expanding HAProxy health check to monitor MongoDB primary and secondary state

Tags: haproxy, mongodb, wireshark

Follow up question regarding the MongoDB health check with HAProxy

[How to construct a MongoDB Health Check in HAProxy?](https://serverfault.com/questions/625492/how-to-construct-a-mongodb-health-check-in-haproxy)

The current solution works well when the focus is on determining if mongo responds, but I am trying to expand the functionality to track based on the status of the database for primary or secondary.   I have tried variations of isMaster without success.   On the MongoDB side with mongosniff or wireshark, the results come across as a query parsing error and no response is posted back to the HAProxy host.

Using the Mongo wire protocol, is there a query available to get the status of a given MongoDB server instead of a the current solution which only allows for tracking on a database response?

Comment: Other option is to write an xinetd script that listens on another port, which runs a mongo command and returns the status.
I have done this by using https://github.com/olafz/percona-clustercheck not for mongo, but for mysql. basic idea should be the same.

Comment: I wrote the original answer and if I was going to attempt this, it would be using the isMaster command - that is what the drivers use, it doesn't require authentication, or take a lock etc.  You would be looking for the boolean located here to be true for writes, false for secondary reads: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/isMaster/#isMaster.ismaster  Not sure how this would actually be useful though, given how the drivers work.

Answer (score 2):

I've created this tcp check following the guide from the MongoDB health check question ([How to construct a MongoDB Health Check in HAProxy?](https://serverfault.com/questions/625492/how-to-construct-a-mongodb-health-check-in-haproxy)) and using the isMaster command (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/isMaster/#isMaster.ismaster) in mongodb as mentioned by Adam C in a comment above  :

```
tcp-check send-binary 3d00000001000000ffffffffd407000000000000746573742e24636d640000000000ffffffff170000000169734d617374657200000000000000f03f00
tcp-check expect binary 0869736d61737465720001
```

The sent binary is this command:

```
mongo --host <IP> --port <port> --eval 'db.isMaster().ismaster'
```

The expected binary is the 'ismaster' element of the response document. The important part is the ending value which is 01 if it's a primary db and 00 if it's a secondary.

I used MongodDB 3.4.4 and HAproxy 1.5.18 .